# Macro with "placeholder" value

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I'm working with a library that includes a set of preprocessor libraries.  One of them is a FOR_EACH style macro which iterates over a `__VA_ARGS__` and calls a user-provided macro for each argument.  The user provided macro is called like: `SOME_MACRO(current_arg)`

However, the problem is that it only works with user-provided macros that take a *single* argument.  I'm trying to do something special which involves both the name of a `struct` and each field in the struct.  The problem is, this requires two arguments to the macro.

Since the library I'm working with only accepts a unary macro, is there some way to "bind" an additional argument to my macro?

As of now, I have to hardcode the name of the struct in my macro.  So, if the `struct` I'm working with is named `Foo`, I have to say:

```
#define MY_MACRO(FIELD) /* do something with &Foo::FIELD */
```

Is there someway I could "bind" a second `STRUCT` argument to the macro, perhaps with some further indirection, so that when the library invokes my macro it would be able to expand as:

```
#define MY_MACRO(FIELD) /* do something with &STRUCT::FIELD */
```

Comment: perhaps you could have `FIELD` be `(A, B)`, so that `A` is the value of `STRUCT` and `B` is the value of `FIELD` (in your expansion)?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: added preprocessor tag, to allow searching the technique explained by @iammilind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use following technique.

```
#define MY_MACRO(FIELD) EXPAND FIELD
#define EXPAND(X, FIELD) X::FIELD()
```

Usage in the below test code:

```
struct foo { static int f() { return 0; } };
struct STRUCT { static int f() { return 1; } };

#define MY_MACRO(FIELD) EXPAND FIELD
#define EXPAND(X, FIELD) X::FIELD()

int main ()
{
  int i = MY_MACRO((STRUCT,f)); // see here braces inside braces
}
```

Above code is expanded to,

```
int main ()
{
  int i = STRUCT::f();
}
```

Comment: Awesome hack :)